# Refreshing Dojo MVC Groups on model change doesn't work for complex objects

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo, requirejs

As shown below, I have a dummy memory store which returns a complex object. I would like to bind this complex object to the form. Because it's a complex object, I am binding the object through two MVC groups. The problem happens when the model is refreshed (through the "Fetch" button). The outer MVC group is refreshed, but the inner one is not. It works only if I manually re-set the `target` property of the inner MVC group:

```
dijit.byId('sub-group').set('target', model.prop7);
```

Is there any other, better way to do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Create dummy store
    var store;
    require(['dojo/store/Memory'], function(Memory) {
        store = new Memory({
            data: [{
                id: 1,
                prop1: 'prop 1 value',
                prop2: 'WA',
                prop7: {
                    prop8: 'prop 4 value',
                    prop9: 'prop 5 value'
                }
            }]
        });
    });

    // Create model for MVC
    var model;
    require([
        'dojo/dom',
        "dojo/parser",
        "dojo/Stateful",
        "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function (dom, parser, Stateful) {
        model = new Stateful();
    });

</script>

<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-props="iconClass: 'dijitIconDatabase'">
    <script type="dojo/on" data-dojo-event="click">
        var data = store.get(1);

        model.set(data);

        //dijit.byId('sub-group').set('target', model.prop7);
    </script>

    Fetch
</button>


<form data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" id="form" data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Group" data-dojo-props="target: model">
    <script type="dojo/require">at: "dojox/mvc/at"</script>

    <div class="row">
        <label for="text">Text:</label>
        <input id="text" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" required="true" data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'prop1')"/>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="sub-group" data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Group" data-dojo-props="target: model.prop7">
        <label for="text2">Text 2:</label>
        <input id="text2" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" required="true" data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'prop8')"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you try to use `dojox.mvc.StatefulModel`?

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't use it because it is deprecated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several things I can say are:

- In general, you need to use [dojox/mvc/at](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/mvc/at.html) to make a widget react to change in model. [dojox/mvc/Group](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/mvc/Group.html) is no exception for that.
- Dojo does not allow you to put two [`data-dojo-type`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/parser.html#parser-parameters) to one element. You may want to consider [`data-dojo-mixins`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/parser.html#data-dojo-mixins).
- To make a data model of nested object, you'll need to use [dojox/mvc/getStateful](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/mvc/getStateful.html). [dojox/mvc/StatefulModel](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/mvc/StatefulModel.html) has been superseded by [dojox/mvc/getStateful](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/mvc/getStateful.html) and [dojox/mvc/StoreRefController](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/mvc/StoreRefController.html) as of 1.8 release.

Here’s a sample code for similar use case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.1/dojo/resources/dojo.css" />
        <link id="themeStyles" rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.1/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: 0, async: 1"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            require([
                "dojo/parser",
                "dojo/store/Memory",
                "dojox/mvc/getStateful"
            ], function(parser, Memory, getStateful){
                model = getStateful({});
                store = new Memory({
                    data: [{
                        id: "mydata",
                        prop1stLevel: "Value of 1st level property",
                        group2ndLevel: {
                            prop2ndLevel: "Value of 2nd level property"
                        }
                    }]
                });
                parser.parse();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="claro">
        <script type="dojo/require">at: "dojox/mvc/at"</script>
        <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-props="iconClass: 'dijitIconDatabase'">
            <script type="dojo/on" data-dojo-event="click">
                require(["dojox/mvc/getStateful"], function(getStateful){
                    model.set("group1stLevel", getStateful(store.get("mydata")));
                });
            </script>
            Fetch
        </button>
        <form id="form" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" data-dojo-mixins="dojox/mvc/Group" data-dojo-props="target: at(model, 'group1stLevel')">
            <div class="row">
                <label for="1st-level">1st level:</label>
                <input id="1st-level" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" required="true" data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'prop1stLevel')"/>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="sub-group" data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Group" data-dojo-props="target: at('rel:', 'group2ndLevel')">
                <label for="2nd-level">2nd level:</label>
                <input id="2nd-level" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" required="true" data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'prop2ndLevel')"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Best, - Akira